# infinite progressbar in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to set the message with big font in Progress dialog in android.

I am using following code to do so,

```
 progress_dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

 progress_dialog.show(About_Us_Activity.this, Html.fromHtml(""), Html.fromHtml("big>Message...</big>"), false);
```

i used the above code in AsyncTask onPreExecute() method and dismissed on onPostExecute method, the issue is that my progress dialog is running infinitely that means it is not dismissing. what is the problem with my code. there is no error shown in log cat.

Comment: did you dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute ?

Comment: are you sure onPostExecute gets called ?

Comment: Yes @prateek, please read the whole question, i already mentioned in question that i have dismissed the progressdialog.

Comment: Can you please confirm your onPostExecute is executed if yes then please share your dismiss part in onPostExecute, It will helpful to track issue.

Comment: i used  this code for dismissing the dialog on onPostExecute if(progressdialog.isShowing())
{
progressdialog.dismiss();
}

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and set a breakpoint at the line where you dismiss the dialog? Doing so, you can at least confirm that dismiss is getting called.

Comment: Make sure onPostExecute executed or not. Please check by putting log.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Custom dialog **progress.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+android:id/progress_large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+android:id/progress_large"
        android:text="Loading.."
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+android:id/progress_large"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.calling progress.xml in java file:
setContentView(R.layout.progress);

3.In AndroidManifest.xml, inside  tag use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"